# UIActivityViewController is throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I ran into issue with UIActivityViewController. When Im trying to share image by doing:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [UIImage(named: "image")], applicationActivities: nil)
```

I get an errors:

```
    2023-10-11 09:45:33.759783+0200 Neview[16037:1721794] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006c60d0 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x15c5a3750.height >= 22   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006c5b80 _UICollectionViewListCellContentView:0x15c5a1ec0.height >= _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x15c5a3750.height + 30   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006c2850 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' _UICollectionViewListCellContentView:0x15c5a1ec0.height == 30   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006c60d0 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x15c5a3750.height >= 22   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

But if I change the UIActivityViewController parameter to something else than UIImage(), for eg:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyCustomUIView()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

it stops getting errors.

Anyone knows what may cause this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to share an empty image? Do you get the issue with a non-empty image?

Comment: That was just an example, I got error even when I try to share non-empty image

Comment: Sadly iOS has several issues with constraints in various UI components. There's nothing you can do except make a nice easy demo app that replicates the problem and submit to Apple as a bug report using feedbackassistant.apple.com